# Does Apache Airflow has rule editor

Tags: airflow

Does apache airflow has rule editor, where we can define multiple rules like "(x>y) && (z==a)" etc.. and later we can integrate these rules in the workflow steps similar to Drools workbench editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, depending on what you need to implement you can use [variables](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/variable.html) to store some data. You can mainly store strings or a json structure.

Using those you can define some kind of structure that will be read inside the DAG. You can even create different tasks dynamically from the value of a Variable.